# promise and collection of loops

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, q

Help me understand what is wrong with my code please.

So what I have to do is to call an async call to get a count. I have made that into a promise.

```
function getCount(client) {
    var xml = "<urn:mgmtISCSIGetTargetList> </urn:mgmtISCSIGetTargetList>";
    client.MgmtServer.MgmtServer.mgmtISCSIGetTargetList(xml, function (err, result) {

        if (err) {
            logger.error(err);
            debug(err);
            return deferred.reject(err);
        }
            deferred.resolve(parseInt(result.list.targetCount));
        }
    });

    return deferred.promise;
};
```

once I get the count using the above promise, I need to make more async calls, as many as the return of the first promise.

The code that suppose to do the later is another promise.
That code is:

```
function az(client, index) {
  var xml = "<urn:mgmtISCSIGetTargetList> </urn:mgmtISCSIGetTargetList>";
    client.MgmtServer.MgmtServer.mgmtISCSIGetTargetList(xml, function (err, result) {

            if (err) {
                return deferred.reject(err);
            }

            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < index; i++) {
                if (1 === i) {
                    console.log('index 1 is bad news');
                    return deferred.reject("Blew up");
                }
            }

            console.log('after the loop');
            deferred.resolve(index);
        }
    );
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

Just for testing purposes, I hard coded for index of 1 reject the promise.
When I put the promises together, I am not seeing what I expect.
The code is:

```
getCount(client).then(
    function (count) {
        return az(client, count).then(console.log);
    }
).catch(
    function (err) {
        console.log('caught an error from outer promise');
        console.log(err);
    }
);
```

the output I get is:

```
3 which is from deferred.resolve(index);
index 1 is bad news which is hard coded failure.
```

I know this is a long post, but anyone sees what I am doing wrong in chaining these 2 promises together?

I changed az to read as:

```
function az(client, index) {
    var xml = "<urn:mgmtISCSIGetTargetList> </urn:mgmtISCSIGetTargetList>";
    client.MgmtServer.MgmtServer.mgmtISCSIGetTargetList(xml, function (err, result) {

            if (err) {
                return deferred.reject(err);
            }

            if (1 === index) {
                console.log('index 1 is bad news');
                return deferred.reject("Blew up");
            }

            console.log('after the loop with index ' + index);
            deferred.resolve(index + 30);
        }
    );
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

Comment: Where do you construct the `deferred` variable?

Comment: What promise library are you using?

Comment: var deffered = require('Q).deferred and I use Q package and deferred

Comment: What output did you expect? What does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resolve (fulfill/reject) a promise only once. That you have `return deferred.reject("Blew up");` inside a loop looks much like a design smell, or wrong understanding.

> I need to make more async calls, as many as the return of the first promise. The code that suppose to do the later is another promise

Every async task should have its own promise. What I had expected from that description was

```
getCount(client).then(function (count) {
    for (var i=0; i<count; i++)
        az(client, i).then(console.log);
})
```

Now you will have a promise returned from each `az` call, so you would have an array of promises that are executing in parallel. If you need to wait for all of them to continue with all their results together, you will need to compose them to a new promise. The Q library does have a helper function for that, named [`Q.all`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#wiki-promiseall). You can use it like this:

```
getCount(client).then(function (count) {
    var promises = [];
    for (var i=0; i<count; i++)
        promises.push(az(client, i));
    return Q.all(promises);
}).then(function(results) {
    console.log("everything went right. All results:", results);
}, function(err) {
    console.log("something (either getCount, or one of the az calls) blew up", err);
});
```

Comment: What I am trying to do is if any of the items in the loop have issues to throw and exception. Is deferred.reject not the correct way to do that?

Comment: Yes, it is, but you seem to have mis-placed the loop. Or does that `mgmtISCSIGetTargetList` method return all the items at once, and you don't even need multiple calls to it?

Comment: i have misplaced the loop. has to be. mgmtISCSIGetTargetList return one item at a time

Comment: Glad to hear my guess was right :-) So does it work when `az()` does produce a promise for a single value?

Comment: no it does not... here what I have now. I use the code you submitted for the array as is and I changed the az to read: as I added above and I see output:
everything went right. All results: [ 3, 3, 3 ]
after the loop with index 0
index 1 is bad news
after the loop with index 2

out of order and never see the "something went wrong error. I will add the az code as I have it.

Comment: `var deffered = require('Q).deferred` sounds wrong - and where exactly did you put that? You need a distinct, new deferred for every promise; so you should have a `var deferred = Q.defer()` in the first line of both the `getCount` and `az` functions.

Comment: very good catch. 

After the change, I see the "exception" thrown going to the .catch clause:
index 1 is bad news
something (either getCount, or one of the az calls) blew up Blew up

but then the array processing continues after index 1 has problems. That is strange, no?

Comment: No. The array processing doesn't "continue", but "still runs". Only when one of the `promises` blew up, the others are not *canceled*, and will still resolve (which is where you are getting your log messages from). However, the `all()` result promise did get rejected immediately, and will never log `"everything went right"`.

Comment: I see, still counter-intuitive in my view, extra processing "running" the rest of the array... So to stop "running" do I have to roll my own  solution by changing the az promise?

Comment: The `Q` library does not yet support a Cancellation API afaik. But does your `mgmtISCSIGetTargetList` method? If you cannot stop the asynchronous task anyway, you don't need to change anything. Or does `az()` do more than that?

Comment: each element of the array makes an async call, mgmtISCSIGetTargetList. So when the array elements continue to run, I am wasting time making the async calls for no reason. By making my az promise smarter, a static flag the says, somebody failed and do nothing, I can prevent the unnecessary processing. But it smells :(

Comment: No, the calls *have* already *been made* in the very beginning (the loop to `count`) - the async tasks just didn't finish when the first of them did signalize a fail. You cannot *prevent* them, but you might *stop* the processing.